# Create Email Reminder for Recurring Calendar Events

Tags: workflow, timer-jobs, custom-actions, sharepoint-calendar

I'm trying to figure out a way to create 2 calendar event items.  1 that sends an email reminder 30 days before it's start time to certain people and the other that sends an email reminder 7 days before start time. These events will be recurring so I know that can be tricky. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the previous links actually allows you to create a recurring reminder for a recurring calendar event in a SharePoint (calendar) list.

I have been searching the web and every site I have found so far (so I may not have actually hit the one that does! If you have found a solution I would like to see the link please) hasn't come close to to anything more than repeatedly posing the need for an OOTB solution to this seemingly basic use case.

Anyway, I have been actively attempting to solve this need.

There are many difficulties in attempting to solve this including the difficulty that a recurring Event actually doesn't have individual items, in the list, for each recurrence of the Event.  The recurring data is actually stored in a hidden Multi Line text column called `RecurringData`? . Subsequently this then causes many rather horrible difficulties to over come.

Firstly, you don't know when the next event is going to occur, secondly the column is multi line text so you are unable to natively use it in other calculated columns to extract specific details from it and thirdly the the contents of the field are in XML for which there is little in the OOTB ways (ie calculated columns (based on Excel formulas) and worse even within a SPD declarative workflow) in which to interrogate and interpret the XML.  For the purpose of explanation, this is the XML within this column for a recurring event recurring `Every 5 month(s) on the third Thursday` of the month :

```
<recurrence>
  <rule>
    <firstDayOfWeek>mo</firstDayOfWeek>
    <repeat><monthlyByDay th="TRUE" weekdayOfMonth="third" monthFrequency="5" /></repeat>
    <repeatForever>TRUE</repeatForever>
  </rule>
</recurrence>
```

As should now be able to understand this as explained so far makes creating a solution quiet a difficult task to accomplish.

The good news is that I am on the final legs of having a solution to this recurring event reminder problem which I will post in the coming weeks when I have had a chance to test it thoroughly. So anyone can have a go at implementation.

Brief overview, the solution adds a number of additional fields to either a Content Type (massive benefit here for being able to enable ANY calendar with events) and/or the actual list. The additional fields include:

```
Reminder Required             Yes/No (do you want reminders for this event?)
Reminder Days Before          Numeric (How many days before the event do you want a reminder?)
Reminder Recipients           People Picker (Who do you want to remind?)
Next Reminder Date            Calculated Date
Recurrence Data               Calculated Single line of Text (converted to SIngle Line from the original  hidden 'RecurrenceData' column)
Recurrence Type               Calculated Single Line of Text
Daily Weekday Reminder        Calculated Numeric
Daily Day Frequency Reminder  Calculated Numeric
Monthly Frequency Reminder    Calculated Numeric
Yearly Frequency Reminder     Calculated Numeric
```

Combined with a relatively simple SPD workflow!

Watch this space if you're interested!

Comment: RaYvA, were you able to solve this? This is something I am working towards as well...

Comment: No followup? :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to create designer WF to send reminder on interval because OOTB WF will not help you send reminder. 
Please refer the below blogs:

http://www.petestilgoe.com/tag/email-reminder-workflow/

http://sp365.co.uk/2011/09/sharepoint-designer-2010-reminder-email-workflow/